# Printf format error for number

Tags: bash, variable, echo, printf

After some `grep`ing and `sed`ing I manage to get a value from a csv cell and assign it to a variable (DBR).

Here come some odd findings

```
echo $DBR
echo "$DBR",
printf "%f" $DBR
```

output:

```
9.1
,.1
: invalid numbersh: line 25: printf: 9.1
```

Comment: thx that was it; if you'd like you can post it as an  answer so I can accept it;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `grep`ing and `sed`ing has failed to remove a trailing carriage return from the value of `DBR` (perhaps originating from DOS-style line endings in the original CSV file).

Ex. given

```
$ printf -vDBR '9.1\r'
$ echo "$DBR" | xxd
00000000: 392e 310d 0a                             9.1..
```

then

```
$ echo $DBR
9.1
$ echo "$DBR",
,.1
$ printf '%f\n' "$DBR"
: invalid number1
0.000000
```